# Keeping track of auto increment columns in a cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a cursor where I needed to copy some rows and insert it into a table with only 1 column different. Say for example I have a table A like this

```
Id     |    CID   |  Country  

 1           X           A    
 2           X           B     
 3           X           C
```

'Id' in this table is auto increment and primary key and Country is the countries visited by that CID. So when I was asked to update the table where every country visited by CID 'X' has  also been visited by CID 'Y'. I wrote a cursor and did an insert into with CID 'Y' and the Country. After I executed my cursor, table A became this:

```
Id     |    CID   |  Country  

 1           X           A    
 2           X           B     
 3           X           C    
 4           Y           A    
 5           Y           B     
 6           Y           C
```

Now there is another table B that is as follows, where AId is the foreign key referencing Id in A.

```
AId    |  AgeOfKids

 1          20
 1          23
 1          28
 2          21
 2          24
 2          29
 3          22
 3          25
```

I want to be able to add rows to this table such that it becomes:

```
AId    |  AgeOfKids

 1          20
 1          23
 1          28
 2          21
 2          24
 2          29
 3          22
 3          25
 4          20
 4          23
 4          28
 5          21
 5          24
 5          29
 6          22
 6          25
```

To explain in words, the AIds that have the same countries in table A must have the same BeIds in table B. Is it possible to accomplish this? Is so, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Everytime I see cursors, a little piece of me dies. What DBMS are you using (SQL Server, Oracle)?

Comment: SQL server 2008 R2. I would have to figure a way that works on sql server 2005 as well since my production is 2005 and dev is 2008 :-|

Comment: Where did `BeId` come from?

Comment: It is a column in table B. I just put it in for an example. It could be anything for that matter. Ages of Aid's kids to give u an example.

Comment: Please don't use cursors.  Every person who follows you (and has to support the code) will thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`OUTPUT` clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
declare @t table (Id int not null,Country char(1) not null)

insert into TableA (CID,Country)
output inserted.id,inserted.Country into @t
select 'Y',Country from TableA where CID = 'X'
```

And then (should be part of the same batch as the above):

```
insert into TableB (AId,AgeOfKids)
select t.ID,b.AgeOfKids
from @t t
 inner join
  TableA a
     on
        t.Country = a.Country and
        a.CID = 'X'
 inner join
  TableB b
     on
       a.ID = b.AId
```

To populate table B.

Comment: Good non cursor workaround.  Here is an expanded example of the OUTPUT clause : http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2008/12/10/sqlserver20052008-output-clause-in-insertupdatedelete-statements/